# (R). Creating table column names from unique rows from selected column in existing table

Tags: r

Well i have for example this data table

```
money   gender  city    age
2000    F       A       21
3341    M       B       19
1256    M       C       25
3421    F       B       35
5633    M       A       45
2314    M       A       21
1234    F       C       26
3535    F       D       61
```

And i need to make new table with unique rows from selected column as new column names.

For example when i select "gender" i should get this table

```
M   F
```

Or when i select "city" i should get this table

```
A   B   C   D
```

Which Command in R will let me do that?

Comment: Check `unique`...

Comment: What will be the rows in the new table? Or do you want only an empty table?

Comment: If `gender` and `city` are factors, you can use `levels(df$gender)` and `levels(df$city)`. Otherwise just use `unique`. See `?unique` and `?levels`.

Comment: I want empty table. Just names of collumns in new table will be used in my shiny application.

Comment: Levels worked. Thanks for advice. But i need to remove this [1] now. But i think i will find how to somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

use **unique ()**

unique(x, incomparables = FALSE, ...)

Comment: It doesent give what i wanted. Or i just dont know something about this command or command is wrong.